# Remove "broadcast" on-screen message while broadcasting with Twitch on Xbox One?

Tags: xbox-one, twitch

When broadcasting with Twitch on Xbox One and unsnap the twitch app, I have a bar near the bottom center of the screen that says something like "Broadcasting, 4 viewers".

Can I remove this bar? I can't find any settings related to it so I suspect it can't be done, but I thought I'd ask just the same.

Answer (score 1):

You can't. Still. Yes, after all these years.